# need for Node.js docker image that run the app when start

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm using AWS Elastic Beanstalk Multicontainer environment.

the problem is when using image node:0.12 or node:argon

the container start then close immediately.

node:argon "node" About a minute ago Exited (0)

after investigation we found that we must build our own image with some commands that will start the app when container initialized.

my question is:

is there any public node image that do this?

we don't want to create a private repository or build any images.

Answer (score 0):

Following is a simple tutorial using argon docker image.

https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/nodejs-docker-webapp/

Sample docker file :

```
FROM node:argon

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json /usr/src/app/
RUN npm install

COPY . /usr/src/app

EXPOSE 8080

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer .. but, unfortunately, Elastic Beanstalk doesn't support Dockerfile .. it work with another file format called Dockerrun.aws.json.

Comment: You can give both dockerfile and dockerrun.aws.json in a .zip file . EBS will build image from dockerfile.

Comment: Oh I missed the multicontainer part. In that case you need to build image. Otherwise how will you put your code in the docker image?

Comment: Putting code in the docker image via "volumes" in dockerrun.aws.json file
 
"volumes": [    
    {
      "name": "node-app",
      "host": {
        "sourcePath": "/var/app/current/node-app"
      }
    }
  ]

and

"containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "name": "node-app",
      "image": "node:0.12",
      "essential": false,
      "memory": 512,
      "mountPoints": [
        {
          "sourceVolume": "node-app",
          "containerPath": "/var/app/"
        }
      ]
    }

Comment: It would be easier to customize image using dockerfile rather than looking for readymade image. What will you do if there is a change in configuration or need to install additional stuff ?

Comment: you point is valid .. but, at least we want to test it before take a decision in which direction we will go.